# Proof for dimension theorem using the first isomorphism theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, proof for the dimension theorem begins by letting $v_1, ...v_k$ be vectors in kernel of $T$ and then extending it to a basis $\left \{ v_1,...,v_k,...,v_n \right \}$ for $V$. Proof is completed by showing the image of $\left \{ v_{k+1},...,v_n \right \}$ is $R(T)$.

But today my professor said that the dimension theorem can be proved easily by using the first isomorphism theorem for groups. ( He might have said that the dimension theorem implies FIT. In fact, my memory is faint. ) Can anyone explain this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:V \rightarrow W$ is a linear map of the vector spaces $V,W$, then the 1. Isomorphism Theorem induces an isomorphism $$V/\ker(f) \cong \text{im}(f).$$
If $V$ is finite dimensional, the dimension of $V/ker(f)$ is $\dim V - \dim (\ker(f))$. Thus

$$\dim V = (\dim V - \dim (\ker (f))) + \dim (\ker (f)) = \dim (\text{im}(f)) +\dim(\ker(f))$$

which I guess you are referring to as dimension theorem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something as follows:

Let $\;T:V\to U\;,\;\;\dim V=n\;$ be a linear map. In particular, $\;T\;$ is a(n abelian groups) homomorphism, so by the FIT for groups we get

$$V/\ker T\cong T(V)\le U\implies \dim\left( V/\ker T\right)=\dim T(V)$$

And since (*) $\;\dim V=\dim\ker T+\dim\left(V/\ker T\right)\;$

we are done

(*) This "since" is pretty easy to show, but it might require a separate proof and, in fact, it is equivalent with what we want to show, so I don't think we really save a lot of time and/or effort.